# Calculate discount in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'd like to post some products to the body and get back the calculated total amount.
But it's getting complicated for me when need to apply discount in that form:

- for every $amount of $product the price reduced to $new-price 
  (let's say every banana is 1$, if customer buy 3 then price is 2$ (but they can buy as many..))

How can I achieve that?

Comment: give some sample documents if you can, and the expected output there are operators like `$cond` or `$size` that can help, but without data its not possible to get an answer

Comment: Please describe your problem more technically. For example, show what your document looks like or what queries did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data

```
db={
  "orders": [
    {
      "_id": "1",
      "customer_id": "1",
      "items": [
        {
          "product_id": "1",
          "quantity": 2
        },
        {
          "product_id": "2",
          "quantity": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "product": [
    {
      "product_id": "1",
      "name": "apple",
      "price": 2,
      "quantity": 1,
      "free": 0
    },
    {
      "product_id": "2",
      "name": "banana",
      "price": 1,
      "quantity": 3,
      "free": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

aggregate

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      _id: "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$items"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "product",
      "localField": "items.product_id",
      "foreignField": "product_id",
      "as": "product_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "product_doc": {
        "$first": "$product_docs"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "total_each": {
        "$multiply": [
          {
            $subtract: [
              "$items.quantity",
              {
                "$multiply": [
                  {
                    $floor: {
                      $divide: [
                        "$items.quantity",
                        "$product_doc.quantity"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "$product_doc.free"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "$product_doc.price"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "total": {
        "$sum": "$total_each"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

result:

apple no discount, banana buy 3 get 1 free

`2x2 + {5-[floor(5/3)x1]}x1 = 8`

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "total": 8
  }
]
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jFS60bZs0KF)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @YuTing. now, how do I apply the discount?
(3 bananas 1$)

Comment: You can figure it out from my data structure. When banana >= 3 , it's 0.667 each. That is what you mean `discount` . You can set many kind of discount like banana >= 10, it's 0.5 each.

Comment: At the moment if customer buys 2 bananas there's still a discount - I don't want that.
also, if customer buys 5 bananas so: 1 discount and 2 regular price (bc discount should only apply to 3).

Comment: I update my answer, you can test it by set different number of banana in mongoplayground.

Comment: Awesome! just what I needed. Thanks @YuTing